# What are the command line options for afconvert?

Tags: macos, terminal, audio

macOS includes a tool called `afconvert` which describes itself this way in the man page.

> Audio File Convert will convert a source audio file to a new audio file with the specified file and data types

However, that's the **entire** man page. What are the command line options required and supported by afconvert? What are some basic examples of how to convert audio files back and forth?

Comment: Try running `afconvert --help`. Many (not all, but afconvert is one of them) command line programs will print some documentation in response to the `--help` option.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Audio File Convert exports to 20 audio file formats and a multitude of codecs, all of which are shown with the `-hf` option.

### Uncompressed Audio

File formats: `AIFC` `AIFF` `NeXT` `Sd2f` `WAVE` `RF64`

The original formats for storing audio files were all uncompressed because these are easy to work with, and can be played by even very early CPUs. However, uncompressed audio files are very large, easily going up to 10 MB/minute. These formats all share similar codec options like `I8` `BEI16` `BEI24` `BEI32` `BEF32` `BEF64`. Smaller numbers give smaller files, but larger numbers give higher quality. If you're not sure what to choose, go with `BEI32` or `LEI32`.

### Compressed Audio

File formats: `3gpp` `3gp2` `adts` `ac-3` `amrf` `m4af` `m4bf` `caff` `ec-3` `flac` `mp4f`

Not every codec is supported by every file format, but you can use this as a guide to get started choosing your codec. Once you've chosen a codec, you can look at the output of `afconvert -hf` to pick a suitable container file format.

- `aac` [MPEG-4 Low Complexity AAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding)
- `aace` MPEG-4 AAC Enhanced Low Delay (without SBR)
- `aacf` MPEG-4 AAC Enhanced Low Delay (with SBR)
- `aacg`
- `aach` [MPEG-4 High Efficiency AAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Efficiency_Advanced_Audio_Coding)
- `aacl` MPEG-4 AAC Low Delay
- `aacp` MPEG-4 High Efficiency AAC Version 2
- `ac-3` AC-3
- `alac` [Apple Lossless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Lossless)
- `alaw` aLaw 2:1
- `drms` Apple DRM
- `ec-3`
- `flac` [Free Lossless Audio Codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAC)
- `paac`
- `pac3`
- `pec3`
- `samr`
- `sawb`
- `QDM2` QDesign2 Music
- `QDMC` QDesign Music
- `Qclp` QUALCOMM PureVoice
- `Qclq` Qualcomm QCELP

(*Note: I have excluded the MPG formats such as MPG3/MP3 from this list because they just [do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435349/how-to-use-afconvert-to-convert-from-caf-to-mp3-format)*.)

### Syntax

Once you've chosen a file format and codec, you run afconvert like this:

```
afconvert -f FORMAT -d CODEC SOURCEFILE [-o DESTINATIONFILE]
```

It is necessary to specify both the file format *and* the codec, otherwise an error is shown. If you omit the `-o` option, afconvert will pick a name and extension based on the other inputs.

### Examples

If you have an audio file called `MyAudio.m4a` you could try these commands.

```
# AIFF
afconvert -f AIFF -d BEI32 MyAudio.m4a -o MyAudio.aiff
```

```
# WAVE
afconvert -f WAVE -d LEI32 MyAudio.m4a -o MyAudio.wav
```

```
# Apple Lossless
afconvert -f m4af -d alac MyAudio.m4a -o MyAudio.m4a
```

```
# FLAC
afconvert -f flac -d flac MyAudio.m4a -o MyAudio.flac
```

```
# AAC
afconvert -f mp4f -d aac MyAudio.m4a -o MyAudio.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried making this into an alias, (the .m4a to .wav conversion), but wasn't able to. I keep getting "unknown error occurred" :O alias 2wav='afconvert -f WAVE -d LEI32 $1 $1.wav'

Comment: @esaruoho Try a shell function instead. `2wav() { afconvert -f WAVE -d LEI32 ${1} ${1}.wav ; }`

Comment: Thanks @Nic much appreciated, seemed to work!!

Comment: To convert a whole folder of files at once you can use something like the following: `for f in *.aif ; do afconvert -f WAVE -d LEI32 "$f" -o "${f%.aif}.wav"; done`

Comment: @esaruoho Put the whole alias value in quotes and escape the dollar symbols with a backslash: `alias 2wav="afconvert -f WAVE -d LEI32 \$1 \$1.wav"`.